# How to scroll an HTML select box to an option without directly selecting that option?

Tags: javascript, html

My issue is that when the page is refreshed, I want the 'select' to be scrolled all the way to the top. However, if the user has scrolled the select box down to view the options (without necessarily even clicking on any of them) prior to the refresh, the 'select' box doesn't return to the top.

I've seen answers where people say to simply use selectedIndex to select the first option in the list, and thus it will automatically scroll to the top, but this is NOT an option. When the page is refreshed, nothing must be selected and thus, the only code I have at the moment is:

```
document.form1.componentselect.selectedIndex = -1;
```

Which is effective at clearing out any selections in the 'componentselect', but does not reset the scroll position.

FYI, I am using straight HTML and JS, no JQuery or anything like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is first select the top item (as you said you don't want to do), but then set it to -1!

```
document.form1.foo.selectedIndex=0;
document.form1.foo.selectedIndex=-1;
```

While I was looking at this, I also figured out how to have it remember what was selected, in case that becomes an issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/qPJ4S/

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible to change the scroll position in traditional selects (select from the tag, no box generated by javascript plugins) because this box is controlled directly by the user's browser and theme, without direct interference by javascript.

I believe the only way to "reset" the display is to force the user to click on the field again, hiding and redisplaying the select tag. But you will need to click to open the box again and it hinders more than helps the user.

Comment: Wow. It seems to me that it would be a very common/basic need for web developers to have their Select boxes reset (to the state they were in when the page initially loaded) on a refresh. And not to have things scrolled all willy-nilly after the refresh. Thanks for the knowledge, but your answer did surprise me!

Comment: I may not have understood the problem correctly, you're talking about the multiple box or the box with just a single line?